# Deploy shiny with shinyproxy - no app showing

Tags: shiny, shinyproxy

I've developed a shiny app and i'm trying to do a first lightweight deploy using shinyproxy.
All installation seems fine. 
I've installed docker, java.

I thought that building a package that wraps the app and other function would be a good idea.
So I developed a package (CI) and `CI::launch_application` is basically a wrapper around `RunApp` function of `shiny` package. This is the code:

```
launch_application <- function(launch.browser = interactive(), ...) {
  runApp(
    appDir = system.file("app", package = "CI"),
    launch.browser = launch.browser,
    ...
  )
}
```

I succesfully built the docker image with this Dockerfile

```
FROM rocker/r-base:latest

## Install required dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    ## for R package 'curl'
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    apt-utils \
    ## for R package 'xml2'
    libxml2-dev \
    ## for R package 'openssl'
    libssl-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    default-jdk \
    default-jre \
  && apt-get clean \
  && R CMD javareconf \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/




## Install major fixed R dependencies
#  - they will always be needed and we want them in a dedicated layer,
#    as opposed to getting them dynamically via `remotes::install_local()`
RUN install2.r --error \
  shiny \
  dplyr \
  devtools \
  rJava \
  RJDBC

# copy the app to the image
RUN mkdir /root/CI
COPY . /root/CI

# Install CI
RUN install2.r --error remotes \
  && R -e "remotes::install_local('/root/CI')"

# Set host and port

RUN echo "options(shiny.port = 80, shiny.host = '0.0.0.0')" >> /usr/local/lib/R/Rprofile.site

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["R", "-e", "CI::launch_application()"]
```

This is my application.yml file

```
proxy:
  title:
  logo-url: http://www.openanalytics.eu/sites/www.openanalytics.eu/themes/oa/logo.png
  landing-page: /
  heartbeat-rate: 10000
  heartbeat-timeout: 60000
  port: 8080
  admin-groups: scientists

  users:
  - name: jack
    password: password
    groups: scientists
  - name: jeff
    password: password
    groups: mathematicians

  authentication: simple

  # Docker configuration
  docker:
    cert-path: /home/none
    url: http://localhost:2375
    port-range-start: 20000
  specs:
  - id: home
    display-name: Customer Intelligence
    description: Segment your customer
    container-cmd: ["R", "-e", "CI::launch_application()"]
    container-image: company/image
    access-groups: scientist

logging:
  file:
    shinyproxy.log
```

When I launch `java shinyproxy.jar` and i visited the url with the port I exposed, I see a login mask.
I logged in with simple authentication ( login is successful from shinyproxy.log) but neither an app is showing nor a list of app.
When I launch the app locally everything is fine.

Thanks

Comment: Probably, there is a misprint in the allowed user group: *access-groups: scientist*, where it must be *scientist**s***.  
Also there is an excessive instruction in *application.yml*, which is already included in the dockerfile:
`container-cmd: ["R", "-e", "CI::launch_application()"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a misprint in the allowed user group in *application.yml* (should be scientist**s** over scientist):

```
 access-groups: scientists
```

Comment: I've posted it again in order the answer could be accepted

Answer (score 1):

Dzimitry is right. It was a typo error: scientist**s** over scientist.