# Shiny app does not appear when deployed using Shinyproxy

Tags: r, shiny, dockerfile, shinydashboard, shinyproxy

I'm trying to learn how to deploy a shiny app using **Shinyproxy**, and I'm using the templated "*euler app*" (from this [repo](https://github.com/openanalytics/shinyproxy-template)), but the application does not appear when I navigate to `http://localhost:4445`. Here's the most similar question I could find, but unfortunately not helpful to my issue: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59249993/deploy-shiny-with-shinyproxy-no-app-showing).

**Background**

All installations seem fine, and I successfully installed Docker and Java.

The Dockerfile and Docker image work locally, no issues there. The command `docker run --rm -p 3838:3838 shiny-euler-app` works.

Here is my Dockerfile (copied from the [repo](https://github.com/openanalytics/shinyproxy-template)):

```
FROM openanalytics/r-base
MAINTAINER Tobias Verbeke "tobias.verbeke@openanalytics.eu"
# system libraries of general use
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libssh2-1-dev \
    libssl1.1
# system library dependency for the euler app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libmpfr-dev
# basic shiny functionality
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('shiny', 'rmarkdown'), repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/')"
# install dependencies of the euler app
RUN R -e "install.packages('Rmpfr', repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/')"
# copy the app to the image
RUN mkdir /root/euler
COPY euler /root/euler
COPY Rprofile.site /usr/lib/R/etc/
EXPOSE 3838
CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/root/euler')"]
```

As well, Shinyproxy works fine with the default `openanalytics/shinyproxy-demo` Docker image, as you can see:

[image]

**Problem**

The issue I have is when I try and supply a different Shiny app and its accompanying `application.yml`. Here is the `application.yml` file I'm using (I've tried to make it as basic as possible, with no authentication, etc):

```
proxy:
  title: Standalone Docker Engine
  port: 4445
  authentication: none
docker:
  url: http://localhost:2375
specs:
- id: euler
  display-name: Euler's number
  container-cmd: ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/root/euler')"]
  container-image: shiny-euler-app
```

Unfortunately, when I run `java -jar shinyproxy-2.4.2.jar` (in the directory which contains the `shinyproxy-2.4.2.jar` file and the `application.yml` file) I get this **blank webpage**:

[image]

For some reason, I am able to **access** the Shinyproxy webpage, but the Dockerized Shiny app **does not appear**.

Would really appreciate any helpful suggestions on where/how I could try and solve this issue. Thanks!